# VS CODE - ARQUIVOS DO CHROME MUDARAM PARA O EXPLORER

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome

Estava com o vs code aberto, ativei o live server e do nada os arquivos mudaram do chrome pro explorer. Como posso resolver isso? Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Olha qual é o seu navegador padrão, isso aconteceu comigo uma vez e eu tinha mudado o navegador padrão para o explorer sem querer.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado!